# phpseclib signing CSR with own CA

Tags: php, ssl, certificate, phpseclib

I want to sign a CSR with my CA. I took some parts of this code from [phpseclib: X.509 Examples](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/examples.html#casigned)

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');
$c = $_POST['csr'];

$CAPrivKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$CAPrivKey->setPassword('PrivatePassword');
$CAPrivKey->loadKey("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,47EF178926906B55

lVtuTcJ1etpRaUT9086Vm5dsop8o5D92VVubcyhI268ZG4frRCBR4yuyORp+zdS2
[...]
gyx636VRV7aekLc6IFHJ56MzZRA/23izSooWqAJLTGEBrc4CWuodj9cc/+p3+9zC
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
");

$issuer = new File_X509();
$issuer->setPrivateKey($CAPrivKey);
$issuer->loadX509("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIK0zCCBrugAwIBAgIJAPzTFDuzmcUcMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGhMQswCQYD
[...]
6F5Ji6w2IfD6xFhgvyTmqYgsae3+DEX6TAJosaI0EJQz6vYeubQb
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
");


$subject = new File_X509();

$subject->loadCSR($c); 


$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->setStartDate('-1 month');
$x509->setEndDate('+1 year');

$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $subject);

echo $x509->saveX509($result);
?>
```

In $csr I've got CSR formatted this way:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIGYMIGFAgAwbzELMAkGA1UEBgwCUEwxCjAIBgNVBAgMAS4xETAPBgNVBAcMCExlb2Frd2RhMQow
[...]
dGVzdC5wbDAQMAsGCSqGSIb3DQEBAQMBADALBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUDAQA=
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

This code gives me error: `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\wamp\www\Math\BigInteger.php on line 1659`

Comment: If you run the equivalent openssl commands on the same server from the command line, how long does the signing take?

Comment: @rlandster Not more than two seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many bits is the key? Do you have gmp or bcmath or openssl installed? Phpseclib uses each of those to speed things up if they're available and if not it'll use it's own internal implementation which is the slowest. Per the [math_biginteger benchmarks on phpseclib.sourceforge.net](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/math/intro.html) the pure php implementation on older versions of php will take a long time even with a 2048 bit key.

Comment: Right, Enabling GMP extension decreased time to about one second. Thanks for help. Another problem that just occurred is, that when I try to open .cdr file, Windows says that it is corrupted.

Comment: How are you trying to open the file?

Comment: I also wouldn't mind knowing how big the key was my own edification. Based on the times you're saying the the stuff is taking my guess would be its a pretty big key. Like 8192 bits or something..

Comment: I just double-click on .cer file(on Windows 7), then a box with error appears. My Root Private key is 8192 bits length

Comment: Oh wow. Good guess on my part lol! I'll play around with getting windows 7 to open it when I get home to a computer. Off hand I'm thinking that maybe .cers need to be in der format - not pem format. I'll test it out and let you know!

Comment: By default phpseclib's File_X509 doesn't set a serial number which means that the serial number defaults to 0. It needs to be non-zero for Windows to take it. So do $x509->setSerialNumber('1'). Or $x509->setSerialNumber('2') or something.